# Python package version not found, but it's clearly there

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to create specific python environment inside docker for reproducible builds, but package `python-opencv` that previously was manually installed refuses to get installed with error:

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv_python==4.7.0 (from versions: 3.4.0.14, 3.4.10.37, 3.4.11.39, 3.4.11.41, 3.4.11.43, 3.4.11.45, 3.4.13.47, 3.4.15.55, 3.4.16.57, 3.4.16.59, 3.4.17.61, 3.4.17.63, 3.4.18.65, 4.3.0.38, 4.4.0.40, 4.4.0.42, 4.4.0.44, 4.4.0.46, 4.5.1.48, 4.5.3.56, 4.5.4.58, 4.5.4.60, 4.5.5.62, 4.5.5.64, 4.6.0.66, 4.7.0.68)
>
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for opencv_python==4.7.0

Command was:

> pip3 install  face_recognition==1.3.0  opencv_python==4.7.0

Inside docker: `ubuntu 22.04; Python 3.10.6; pip 22.0.2`

Why pip3 cannot find `opencv_python` version `4.7.0` since it's clearly in the list of available packages? What's the best way to create reproducible python environment when building docker image?

Comment: You told it to install _exactly_ version 4.7.0, which was not in the list of available versions.  4.7.0 is not the same as 4.7.0.68.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the exact version, so:

```
opencv_python==4.7.0.68
```

Otherwise, you can ask for approximate versions using one of the following:

```
opencv_python~=4.7.0
opencv_python==4.7.0.*
```